# Diagonalization of a Circulant Matrix of Even Size

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, diagonalization, circulant-matrices

> **Lemma 1:** Consider $A$ be an $e\times e$ [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), denoted with $A=circ(a_0,a_1,\cdots , a_{e-1})$, over the $GF(2^q)$. Let
>   $V=[\gamma^{-ij}]$, $0\leq i,j<e$, be an $e\times e$ [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
>    where $\gamma$ is an element in $GF(2^q)$ of order $e$. Then,
>   $VAV^{-1}$ is an $e\times e$ [diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix), denoted by $A^{F}$,
>   whose $t$h diagonal element $0\leq t <e$, equals:

$$ A^{F}=dig\,(\,
 \sum_{i=0}^{e-1}\,a_i \, , \, \sum_{i=0}^{e-1}\,\gamma^{i}a_i \, , \,
 \cdots \, , \, \sum_{i=0}^{e-1}\,\gamma^{(e-1)i}a_i\, ) $$

> In particular, the diagonal vector of $A^{F}$ is the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of
>    $(a_0,a_1,\cdots , a_{e-1})$.
>    [[1]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6134665/)

In Lemma $1$, we suppose that $e\mid 2^q-1$ which implies that $e$
 should be an odd number. Therefor, every circulant matrix of odd size,
 over $GF(2^q)$, can be diagonalized.

> *My question:* How to  diagonalize a circulant matrix over $GF(2^q)$ of even size?

*My try:* Although we have no elements of even order in $GF(2^q)$, I try as follows: Let $A$ be an $2n\times 2n$ circulant matrix over
 $GF(2^q)$. Consider $V=van(0,1,\gamma , \gamma^2,\cdots ,
 \gamma^{2n-2})$ be a Vandermonde matrix of $2n$ size where $\gamma$ is
 an elemnet of order $2n-1$. I construct $VAV^{-1}$, but the result was
 not a diagonal matrix. I have no idea to answer this question.

> Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't see anything very useful to add to Lord Shark's answer (+1). We can rephrase this in the language of representation theory of groups. Maschke's theorem fails in general (and with the regular representation in particular) when the characteristic of the field is a factor of the order of the group. Here we are looking at the regular representation of a cyclic group of an even order in characteristic two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you cannot. Consider a size $2$ circulant
$$A=\pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}$$
over a field of characteristic $2$. Its characteristic polynomial
is $X^2+a^2+b^2$, which has repeated zeros. It is only diagonalisable
if it is already diagonal, that is if $b=0$.

Comment: In practical,I work with size more than $6$. Maybe, it was better to mentioned in question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It won't work with any even size; you can use a block matrix to show that. It's just easier to write down a size 2 counterexample...